# SQLite loads items from the previous group, doesn’t filter by foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Database consist of levels and each level consist of several quizzes.

Level 1 consist of 3 quizzes

Level 2 has 10 quizzes. And so on...

Level 1 is OK, as should be 3 quizzes are there.

When I open Level 2 it shows me quizzes from 1 to 10 as it should be, **BUT** the problem is inside 1 - 3 quizzes **first 3 quizzes are actually from Level 1**, and from quiz 4 to quiz 10 my Level 2 goes(where 7 quizzes are left). Where I forgot to filter, or do it not right way?

```
public class QuizDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


.......skip here....

@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}

private void addJLPTLevel(JLPTLevel jlptLevel) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(JLPTLevelsTable.COLUMN_NAME, jlptLevel.getName());
    cv.put(JLPTLevelsTable.COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID, jlptLevel.getLevelID());
    db.insert(JLPTLevelsTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}

private void addQuizList(ListQuiz listQuiz) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(QuizListTable.COLUMN_NAME, listQuiz.getName());
    cv.put(QuizListTable.COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID, listQuiz.getLevelID());
    db.insert(QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}

private void addQuestion(Question question) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1, question.getOption1());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2, question.getOption2());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3, question.getOption3());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4, question.getOption4());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NB, question.getAnswerNB());
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID, question.getListTest());
    db.insert(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}


public ArrayList<ListQuiz> getNListQuiz(int NListID) {
    ArrayList<ListQuiz> nQuizList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();

    String selection = QuizListTable.COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID + " = ? ";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(NListID)};

    Cursor c = db.query(
            QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ListQuiz nQuizLevel = new ListQuiz();
            nQuizLevel.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuizListTable._ID)));
            nQuizLevel.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuizListTable.COLUMN_NAME)));
            nQuizLevel.setLevelID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuizListTable.COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID)));
            nQuizList.add(nQuizLevel);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return nQuizList;
}


public ArrayList<Question> getNLevelQuestions(int quizListID) {
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();

    String table = QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + "JOIN" + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME +
            " ON " + QuizListTable._ID + "=" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID;
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            QuestionsTable._ID + " AS " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + "_" + QuestionsTable._ID,
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID,
            QuizListTable._ID + " AS " + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME + "_" + QuizListTable._ID,
            QuizListTable.COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID,
            QuizListTable.COLUMN_NAME
    };


    String selection = QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID + " = ? ";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(quizListID)};

    Cursor c = db.query(
            QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable._ID)));
            question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
            question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
            question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
            question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4)));
            question.setAnswerNB(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NB)));
            question.setListTest(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID)));
            questionList.add(question);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    return questionList;
}
}
```

QuizContractor.java

```
package com.hfad.jlpt1quiz;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class QuizContract {

private QuizContract() {
}
public static class JLPTLevelsTable implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "test_level";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "LevelName";
    public static final String COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID = "LevelID";

}

public static class QuizListTable implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "quiz_list";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_JLPTLevel_ID = "LevelID";
    //QuizListTable._ID to QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID
}

public static class QuestionsTable implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "quiz_questions";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION1 = "option1";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION2 = "option2";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION3 = "option3";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION4 = "option4";
    public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER_NB = "answer_nb";
    //It should be foreign key for QuizListTable._ID
    public static final String COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_ID = "quiz_list_id";
}
```

}

Quiz Level

[image]

Quiz lists

[image]

Quiz questions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At a guess you are expecting the definition of a foreign key to automatically extract data according to the defined foreign keys. That will not be the case. All defining a foreign key does is add a constraint (rule) that must be followed saying that to insert a row into the table (child) that references another table **MUST** (if foreignKey**Constraints**Enabled is true). As such you have to **JOIN** tables **ON** the reference to get data from both tables.

Assuming that you have two tables

**quizlist** which has;

- a column for the **id** of the individual quizlist (_id in the picture),
- a column for the **name**, and
- a column for the **level** (not sure why an id in your picture, it just appears that a number suffices as the picture shows rows have the same level)

and **question** which has;

- a column for the **id** of the individual question
- a column that references the quizlist (and therefore level).

  - *(minimal columns included for brevity/demonstration)*

Then using the following to populate the tables :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS question;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS quizlist;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quizlist (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, level INTEGER, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS question (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question TEXT, quizlist_reference REFERENCES quizlist(id));

INSERT INTO quizlist (level,name) VALUES (1,'P 1'), (1,'P 2'),(1,'P 3'),(2,'P 4'),(2,'P 5'),(3,'P 6'),(3,'P 7');
INSERT INTO question (question, quizlist_reference) VALUES
    ('Q1',1),('Q2',6),('Q3',2),('Q4',4),('Q5',3),('Q6',1),('Q7',1),('Q8',1),('Q9',3),('Q10',3),('Q11',3),
    ('Q12',2),('Q13',4),('Q14',5),('Q15',3),('Q16',4),('Q17',6);
```

Will result in two tables :-

**quizlist** :-

[image]

**question** :-

[image]

As can be seen no the level and the name of the level are not included data is gathered. Instead if you ran a SELECT query using (only user friendly data is the question, it's level name and it's level):-

```
SELECT question, name, level 
    FROM question 
        JOIN quizlist ON quizlist.id = quizlist_reference 
    ORDER BY question ASC;
```

The result would be :-

[image]

- Note sorting (ORDER BY) by question isn't at all helpful in this case.
- As can be seen for each question the respective level and the level name is now obtained.

It's now a simple step to select all questions for a level, all that is needed is a WHERE clause e.g. `WHERE level = 1` to be included.

So using :-

```
SELECT question  
FROM question 
    JOIN quizlist ON quizlist.id = quizlist_reference 
WHERE level = 1 
ORDER BY question ASC;
```

Will result in :-

[image]

Similarly :-

```
SELECT question  
FROM question 
    JOIN quizlist ON quizlist.id = quizlist_reference 
WHERE level = 2 
ORDER BY question ASC;
```

Will result in :-

[image]

**It's impossible to provide a more specific answer without guessing, as there is no indication in the questions as to the foreign keys, column definitions etc. As such you will need to apply the principles shown appropriately.**

#### Applying the Query to Android

Note that to use the SQLiteDatabse **query** method the table along with the JOIN are supplied via the first parameter as a String.

Additionally if you have like named columns (e.g. in the example above both tables have an **id** column) a Cursor does not include the table name, therefore the Cursor will have columns with the same name and the getColumnIndex method will not necessarily get the right data (I believe it will get the last such column). As such it is advisable to give the columns specific names with an AS clause (this as part of the second parameter).

As such using adapting your code to suit the above tables a method such as the following could get questions at a particular level :-

```
public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionsByLevel(int level) {
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();

    String table = QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + 
         " JOIN " + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME + 
         " ON " + QuizListTable.COLUMN_ID  + "=" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTIONS_QUIZ_LIST_REFERENCE;
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ID + 
            " AS " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + "_" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ID, //<<<<<<<< make returned ID column (from questions table) unique name
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION,
            QuizListTable.COLUMN_ID + 
            " AS " + QuizListTable.TABLE_NAME + "_" + QuizListTable.COLUMN_ID, //<<<<<<<<<< make returned ID column (from quizlist table) unique name
            QuizListTable.COLUMN_LEVEL,
            QuizListTable.COLUMN_NAME
        };
    String selection = QuizListTable.COLUMN_QUIZ_LIST_LEVEL + "= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(quizListID)};

    Cursor c = db.query(
            table,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    ...............
```

- **Note** the above is intended only as an in-principle example. It has not been tested, so may contain some errors. Additionally :-

  - Constants are along the lines of how they may be coded based upon what appear to be conventions (wasn't going to spend time trying to decipher the limited code provided)
  - Additional columns have been added for demonstration, the above would equate to `SELECT question.id AS question_id,question,quizlist.id AS quizlist_id, level, name FROM question JOIN quizlist ON quizlist.id = quizlist_reference WHERE level = 2`